# enlarging frame around icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Is there any way to enlarge that border to 60px (like input)?

https://jsfiddle.net/p5b171tg/1/

HTML:

```
<form>
<span class="frejm"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Name"></span>
</form>
```

CSS:

```css
input[type=text] {
    height: 60px;
    border-width: 1px solid;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    width: 90%;
}

.fa-user-circle-o{
    padding-top:60px;
    color: white;
}

.frejm{
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Like input? means height of icons same as input.

Comment: @frnt i want red border aroung icon to be 60 px to be exact, is it possible?

Comment: @Miyagi The stylesheet ver. 4.6.3 wasn't working changed to 4.7.0 See working Snippet or Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/26v8p6L5/

Comment: @Miyagi Updated with 2 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input[type=text] {
  height: 60px;
  border-width: 1px solid;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  flex: 100;
}

.frejm {
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.fa-user-circle-o {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/19445204e2.js"></script>
<form>
  <span class="frejm">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Name">
  </span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick:

```css
.frejm {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 24px 0;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

input[type=text] {
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    width: 90%;
}
```